# FLEX AS3 convert JSON to array

Tags: json, actionscript-3

I have the following JSON string:

```
"["Dog","Cat","Mouse","Monkey","Horse"]"
```

I want to create a string array in ActionScript from this. Is this possible in AS3?

Answer (score 2):

[JSON.parse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse()) converts from JSON to AS3, and [JSON.stringify()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#stringify()) does the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a JSON parser like [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) to extract the data.

example:

```
var results:Array = JSON.decode(urlloader.data).result;

for each(var youritem:Object in results) {
    trace(youritem.codeD);
}
```

[Download as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

Comment: There is a native support for JSON in Actionscript for quite a long time. No need to use 3rd party libs

Comment: Unless you're targeting Flash Player version < 11